# Unity astar pathfinding project - how to pick a random position from the grid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, a-star

I bought astarpathfinding project pro recently.
I am making enemy ai and I want it to move randomly before it finds its target.
My project is in 2d.
How do I pick a random position on the grid?
if you can, can you show me some example of it?

Comment: Do you know how to generate 2 random numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure about the plugin that you bought, but If you are using tilemaps, you could iterate over every tile in each tilemap in your grid(only once on level loading) and generate a random number of x and y to choose a valid tile position from and make the Ai move there using the A* algorithm.

Edit: May not be the best way to write this, but this is how I iterated over them in the past, you can add or change things in it for your future needs if you want.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
 public class TileMapCollision : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject gridObject;
    private TileBase tile;
    public List<Vector3> StoredStaticSolidTilePositions;
    private void Awake()
    {
        TileSearch();
    }

    private void TileSearch()
    {
        List<Tilemap> tilemaps = gridObject.GetComponentsInChildren<Tilemap>().ToList();
        foreach (Tilemap tilemap in tilemaps)
        {
            tilemap.CompressBounds();
            BoundsInt TilemapBounds = tilemap.cellBounds;
            for (int x = TilemapBounds.xMin; x < TilemapBounds.xMax; x++)
            {
                for (int y = TilemapBounds.yMin; y < TilemapBounds.yMax; y++)
                {
                    Vector3Int localPos = new Vector3Int(x,y, (int)tilemap.transform.position.z);
                    Vector3 worldPos = tilemap.CellToWorld(localPos);
                    if (tilemap.HasTile(localPos))
                    {
                        if (tilemap.CompareTag("Solid"))
                        {
                            StoredStaticSolidTilePositions.Add(worldPos);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow that sounds perfect! I am using tilemap now. can you show me how I could iterate over every tile in each timemap?

Comment: Why would you iterate over every tile just to generate one random grid position?

Comment: @derHugo yes, this is an overkill for this problem but though it would be good for him to have that data for his later uses in pathfinding and such.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what tool you are using or how exactly your "grid" looks like but from the comments it sounds like you have a [`TileMap`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.html).

In general for picking a random number from a value there is [`Random.Range`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html). (Note that the second (upper) parameter is **exclusive** for `int`.)

Then you can get [`TileMap.size`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap-size.html) and simply generate a position from three random indices within the `TileMap`'s dimensions

```
var gridSize = tilemap.size;
var randomPos = new Vector3Int(Random.Range(0, gridSize.x), Random.Range(0, gridSize.y), Random.Range(0, gridSize.z));
var randomTile = tilemap.GetTile(randomPos);
```